# Basic confusion about direct sums and orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a vector space has a not necessarily orthogonal direct sum
decomposition $V = A \oplus B \oplus C$, which means that 
every $v \in V$ has a unique decomposition $v = a + b + c$, where
$a \in A$, $b \in B$ and $c \in C$. Suppose $A = {\rm span}\left\{a\right\}$. Now, let $v^{\perp_A}$ represent the
component of $v$ perpendicular to $A$, that is, 
$$ v^{\perp_A} =  v - \langle a, v\rangle a/||a||^2.$$ 
Therefore, $v^{\perp_A}$ necessarily $\in B\oplus C$ since $v^{\perp_A} = 0 + v^{\perp_A}$, where $0 \in A$. Since $v = v^{\perp_A} + (v - v^{\perp_A})$ is valid decomposition for any $v$ and unique,  $B\oplus C$ and $A$
are perpendicular subspaces. In other words, if a subspace in a direct
sum is spanned by only 1 vector, it must be perpendicular to all other
subspaces in the direct sum. Please let me know if that is wrong!

Comment: What happens for two nonorthogonal lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: They can still form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ if they are linearly independent. So, I guess what I said is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*:
$$v^{\bot_A} = v - \frac {\langle a, v \rangle}{\lVert a \rVert^2} a = (a + b + c) - \frac {\langle a, v \rangle}{\lVert a \rVert^2} a  = \left (1 - \frac {\langle a, v \rangle}{\lVert a \rVert^2} \right ) a + b + c.$$

Comment: This gives $\langle b+c,a \rangle = \langle a, v \rangle - \langle a, a \rangle \neq 0 $. So, what I said is not true! Thank you very much!

Comment: So, what is true is $A^\perp \subseteq B\oplus C$ and what I said in the question is not true!